# wrapping HTML code in one line - or removing spaces and lines

Tags: c#, html, regex, visual-studio, replace

I have some email templates written in HTML format, and i need to use it in my code behind to pass some values.

you know in code behind i want to pass it to the Message Body property so it should be one line,

is there any easy why to do so, Regular expression replace or any other trick to avoid the manual formatting,

Comment: `removing space?` can you be more clear with that...

Comment: and if you remove newline character it would change your message and the message would not appear like the user wanted it to be

Comment: I mean only spaces and lines between Html tags,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand completly what you're trying to do. But if you have some kind of constant multilined text that you would like to insert into a variable, you can do it using the `@` keyword.

This, for instance, will compile just fine:

```
 mailMessage.Body = @"<html>
                          <head>
                              <title>Test</title>
                          </head>
                          <body>
                             <div> .... ";

 mailMessage.Subject = ....
```

Of course, constants should be used instead, but this is just an example.

Comment: i guess this is what he wants